No keyboard shortcut to reopen the last closed doc in Preview?
I often have multiple tabs open in Preview. Sometimes, I close a tab that I again want the next instant. I have been doing this the old-fashioned inefficient way by opening the file by navigating through a chain of folders in Finder, or sometimes by a quick Spotlight search. I know that while in non-full-screen mode, one can also do a quick three-finger swipe down, showing the recently closed docs. However, this is not available for the full-screen mode which is my oft-go-to.
In this situation, a usual "restoring" keyboard shortcut like cmd + shift + T would truly be a godsend. Is there any such functionality available? Or some workaround?

What's wrong with the Open Recent menu?

@Tetsujin Ah! I didn't know of it. But then again, it's not efficient for someone who has to often reopen those recents.
